# Difference between metalLB and NodePort

Tags: networking, kubernetes

What is difference between **MetalLB** and **NodePort**?

Answer (score 2):

A node port is a built-in feature that allows users to access a service from the IP of any k8s node using a static port. The main drawback of using node ports is that your port must be in the range 30000-32767 and that there can, of course, be no overlapping node ports among services. Using node ports also forces you to expose your k8s nodes to users who need to access your services, which could pose security risks.

MetalLB is a third-party load balancer implementation for bare metal servers. A load balancer exposes a service on an IP external to your k8s cluster at any port of your choosing and routes those requests to yours k8s nodes.

Answer (score 0):

MetalLB can be deployed either with a simple Kubernetes manifest or with Helm.
MetalLB requires a pool of IP addresses in order to be able to take ownership of the ingress-nginx Service. This pool can be defined in a ConfigMap named config located in the same namespace as the MetalLB controller. This pool of IPs must be dedicated to MetalLB's use, you can't reuse the Kubernetes node IPs or IPs handed out by a DHCP server.

A NodePort is an open port on every node of your cluster. Kubernetes transparently routes incoming traffic on the NodePort to your service, even if your application is running on a different node.